# How to replace a string in the first occurrence

Tags: livecode

I want to replace a string in the first occurrence. While using the following code it well replaces all match cases. How I change my code? Can anyone help?

```
on mouseUp
    replace "Malayalam" with "English" in field "text"
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wordOffset function:

```
on mouseUp
   set the wholeMatches to true -- OPTIONAL
   put wordOffset("Malayalam",field "text") into N
   if N <> 0 then put "English" into word N of field "text"
end mouseUp
```

The optional line will cause replacement to occur only for an exact match of the source word.  For example, "Malayalam" will be replaced, but "Malayalamm" will not.

There are some cases where wholeMatches must be used, for example, to replace the word "is" in the following sentence:

This is some text.

If wholeMatches is NOT enabled, LiveCode will find the first occurrence of "is" which is in the word "This".

Comment: Thank you Scott Rossi Great coding

Comment: Scott, setting wholeMatches to true will still cause the wordOffset to match "malayalam" in your example. The difference between "Malayalam" and "malayalam" would be captured by setting the caseSensitive property to true rather than the wholeMatches property.